# How to fix: passing argument 1 of 'sutuntopla' makes pointer from integer without a cast warning?

Tags: c

I want to initialize an 5x6 array and pass it to the function where i want to get sum of each column of array.But i keep getting the warning where should i fix ?

```
int sutuntopla(int b[5][6], int uzunluk)
{

    int i,j;
    int sum = 0;

    for(j = 0 ; j < uzunluk ; j++ ) 
    {

        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            sum+=b[i][j];
        }

        printf("Sutun %d toplami=%d\n",(j+1),sum);

        sum=0;

    }       
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    int a[5][6] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,5,6,7},{1,2,5,6,7,8},{1,3,8,9,10,9},{1,4,4,4,5,6}};

    sutuntopla(a[5][6],6);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work.

```
//Here you can make the return type void
int sutuntopla(int b[5][6], int uzunluk)
{

    int i,j;
    int sum = 0;   

    for(j = 0 ; j < uzunluk ; j++ )
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
        {
            sum += b[i][j];
        }

        printf("Sutun %d toplami=%d\n", (j+1), sum);
        sum = 0;

    }  

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    int a[5][6] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,5,6,7},{1,2,5,6,7,8},{1,3,8,9,10,9},{1,4,4,4,5,6}};

    sutuntopla(a, 6);
    //When you are passing an array, you just write its name,
    //like here for a.
    //It passes the base address of the array to the function.
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You just posted a code dump instead of explaining the problem, and you made unwarranted and irrelevant assumptions.

Comment: @JosephSible, yea I figured that out now, I misread the question, sorry for that. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Error is in this line in `main`:-

```
sutuntopla(a[5][6],6);
```

You just need to pass `a` to your function. `a[5][6]` tries to access the element at that particular location which is of type `int` to function expecting `int[][]` and also causes index out of bounds.

Comment: @barkin7 Welcome, also if you don't need to return any value from that function make it to be of type `void`.

Comment: The function does not expect `int[][]` - there is no such type in C, but `int (*)[6]`.